# remove element from hash based on pattern

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash that looks like this:

```
{ "cell_number" => 1234567,  "lead source" => [ "referrel", "web", "ad" ], "lead source_selected" => "web" }
```

Now if there is a pattern where the key contains "x_selected", then I want to return the entire hash, except for the x key. So in this case I want to return everything but "lead source":

```
{ "cell_number" : 1234567,  "lead source_selected" : "web" }
```

My attempt seems to work:

```
 h = { "cell_number" => 1234567,  "lead source" => [ "referrel", "web", "ad" ], "lead source_selected" => "web" }
 h.collect do |k,v|
  if k =~ /(.+)_selected$/
    h.delete( $1 )
  end
 end
 => [nil, nil, ["referrel", "web", "ad"]] 
 > h
 => {"cell_number"=>1234567, "lead source_selected"=>"web"}
```

But is there a more ruby way to do this?

Comment: If there is a key `'X_selected'` then you want to remove `'X'` from the hash, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward solution:

```
h = { "cell_number" => 1234567,
      "lead source" => [ "referrel", "web", "ad" ],
      "lead source_selected" => "web" }

bad_keys = h.each_with_object([]) do |(k,_),a|
  prefix = k[/(.+)(?=_selected$)/]
  a << prefix if prefix
end
  #=> ["lead source"]
h.reject { |k,_| bad_keys.include?(k) }
  #=> {"cell_number"=>1234567, "lead source_selected"=>"web"}
```

Note this uses [Hash#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject) (not [Enumerable#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject)). `(?=_selected$)` in the regex is a positive lookahead. `h` is not mutated.

Comment: I just add this link here because this helped me to understand when to use each_with_object and reduce (inject): http://www.bbs-software.com/blog/2013/11/22/rubys-injectreduce-and-each_with_object/

Answer (score 1):

I think that the [reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Hash.html#method-i-reject) method of Hash will do what you want.
Here is an example, followed by output  (I probably got the pattern wrong, but you can see how it works here, anyway):

```
myhash = { "cell_number" => 1234567,  "lead source" => [ "referrel", "web", "ad" ], "lead source_selected" => "web" }
puts 'the original hash'
p myhash

puts 'the element rejected by key (exact match)'
p myhash.reject{|k, v| k == 'lead source'}

puts 'same result using regular expression'
p myhash.reject{|k, v| k =~ /^lead source$/}

puts 'the hash is unaffected...'
p myhash

puts '... unless reject! is used instead of reject ...'
myhash.reject!{|k, v| k =~ /^lead source$/}
p myhash
```

here is the output

```
the original hash
{"cell_number"=>1234567, "lead source"=>["referrel", "web", "ad"], "lead source_selected"=>"web"}
the element rejected by key (exact match)
{"cell_number"=>1234567, "lead source_selected"=>"web"}
same result using regular expression
{"cell_number"=>1234567, "lead source_selected"=>"web"}
the hash is unaffected...
{"cell_number"=>1234567, "lead source"=>["referrel", "web", "ad"], "lead source_selected"=>"web"}
... unless reject! is used instead of reject ...
{"cell_number"=>1234567, "lead source_selected"=>"web"}
```

Edit: adds response to comment:

Ah, I see... variables can be used by interpolation in the regular expression.
They can contain part or all of the expression.  For examples:

```
phrase="lead source"
p myhash.reject{|k, v| k =~ /^#{phrase}$/}

pattern="^lead source$"
p myhash.reject{|k, v| k =~ /#{pattern}/}
```

Hope I understood and that this helps at all.

Comment: In your example, you are hardcoding 'lead source', but I wouldn't know the actual name of key. I just know that a key x must be removed if the hash also includes a x_selected, where x can be any word.

Comment: (removed this reply and add it in my previous answer for formatting.)

Comment: Further to @Donato's comment, the central point of the question is to determine which key/value pairs (if any) are to be removed, which must be done in code, not by visual inspection.

Comment: @Donato, if that missed the point let me know and I'll remove it.